# Is there any function in OpenCV to find the intersection, union and complements of two cv::Rect

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there any function in OpenCV to find the intersection, union and complements of two `cv::Rect`?

I can write them by myself, but I hope there are some fast function in OpenCV to do this.

Searching documentation, did not any function.

## Edit 1

As some explained, there is no union and complements for rects, so I looked at the avaliable functions and I found that in my case, I can use

```
rect = rect1 | rect2 (minimum area rectangle containing rect1 and rect2 )
```

instead of union. For complement, I need a similar function that defines as:

```
 rect=rect1 || rect2 (maximum area rectangle containing rect1 but not rect2 )
```

this is shown in the following images:

[image]
[image]

`rect1` is yellow, `rect2` is red and result is blue.

What is the fastest way to write this function?

Comment: why would you choose the blue rect and not the yellow rect beyond the blue rect, or that yellow rect part + the blue rect?

Comment: @Micka Can not understand what you mean? The yellow rect is the big rect that has all of the blue rect ( it is behind the blue rect so you can see it,) it also has a part shard with red rect. The blue rect is a rect that you can draw which is completely inside yellow rect (rect1), but has no intersection with Red rect and has maximum area.

Comment: I mean that the lower-left part of the big yellow rect is imho bigger than the blue rect. And if you combine the blue rect and the lower-left part of the yellow rect, it becomes even bigger (without touching the red rectangle).

Comment: @Micka You are right, my drawing is wrong! I am going to update it.

Comment: @Micka Updated the drawing to reflect what you said.

Comment: what if there are multiple solutions? e.g. the red rectangle intersects a quare in same height/width so that there are 2 rectangle candidates with the same size?

Comment: @Micka: Interesting! Maybe return the first one. It doesn't matter which one, or maybe return a vector or maybe having a parameter which says which one to return (for example the one with longest side on x direction, or the one longest side lays on Y direction.)

Comment: added another answer that handles only your complement definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your definition of `complement` you can use this function:

```
cv::Rect RectWithoutRect(cv::Rect r1, cv::Rect r2)
{
    // 32 bit integer values:
    int minVal = -2147483648;
    int maxVal =  2147483647;

    // rectangles that define the space left, right, top and bottom of r2
    cv::Rect leftOf  = cv::Rect(cv::Point(minVal, minVal), cv::Point(r2.x, maxVal)); // rect covering the whole area left of r2
    cv::Rect topOf   = cv::Rect(cv::Point(minVal, minVal), cv::Point(maxVal, r2.y)); // rect covering the whole area top of r2
    cv::Rect rightOf = cv::Rect(cv::Point(r2.x+r2.width, minVal), cv::Point(maxVal, maxVal)); // rect covering the whole area left of r2
    cv::Rect bottomOf= cv::Rect(cv::Point(minVal, r2.y+r2.height), cv::Point(maxVal,maxVal)); // rect covering the whole area top of r2

    // intersect the spaces with r1 to find regions of r1 that lie left, right, top and bottom of r2
    cv::Rect allExterior[4];
    allExterior[0] = leftOf;
    allExterior[1] = topOf;
    allExterior[2] = rightOf;
    allExterior[3] = bottomOf;

    // now choose the biggest one
    int biggestSize = 0;
    cv::Rect biggestRect(0,0,0,0);

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<4; ++i)
    {
        cv::Rect intersection = allExterior[i] & r1;
        int size = intersection.width * intersection.height ;
        if(size > biggestSize)
        {
            biggestSize = size;
            biggestRect = intersection;
        }
    }

    return biggestRect;
}
```

with a tiny test program:

```
int main()
{
    cv::Mat output = cv::Mat(512,512,CV_8UC3,cv::Scalar(255,255,255));


    cv::Rect r1 = cv::Rect(128,128,256,256);

    //cv::Rect r2 = cv::Rect(300,299, 128,128);
    cv::Rect r2 = cv::Rect(150,140, 50,50);

    cv::Rect intersection = r1 & r2;

    cv::rectangle(output, r1, cv::Scalar(0,255,255),-1);
    cv::rectangle(output, r2, cv::Scalar(0,0,255),-1);

    //cv::rectangle(output, intersection, cv::Scalar(255,0,0),-1);

    cv::Rect rWithoutR = RectWithoutRect(r1, r2);
    cv::rectangle(output, rWithoutR, cv::Scalar(255,0,0),-1);


    cv::imshow("output", output);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

you can easily modify the `RectWithoutRect` function to return a vector of "all biggest rects" if you like.

PS: forgot to check the size of the rectangle after function return to find out whether a legal rectangle is returned or not.

To improve performance you can optimize the code and/or test whether r1 and r2 intersect at all, before calling the function.

here are some test results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hint : use .area() instead of `intersection.width * intersection.height`.
use `vector<Rect> allExteriors = { topOf, leftOf, bottomOf, rightOf };`

Answer (score 15):

From [OpenCV doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.2/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html#details):

```
In addition to the class members, the following operations on rectangles are implemented:

rect = rect +/- point (shifting a rectangle by a certain offset)
rect = rect +/- size (expanding or shrinking a rectangle by a certain amount)

rect += point, rect -= point, rect += size, rect -= size (augmenting operations)
rect = rect1 & rect2 (rectangle intersection)
rect = rect1 | rect2 (minimum area rectangle containing rect2 and rect3 )
rect &= rect1, rect |= rect1 (and the corresponding augmenting operations)
rect == rect1, rect != rect1 (rectangle comparison)
```

These only cover operators that always result in another rect, so complement isn't here. you would have to work with masks there...

Since you are asking for complement and union, I'm not sure if `cv::Rect` is the right thing to work with. Maybe masks are better suited to fulfill your needs.

for `CV_8UC1` masks (`mask1` and `mask2` must have same size):

```
union = mask1+mask2
complement = 255-mask 
intersection = mask1.mul(mask2)
```

To create a mask from a `cv::Rect` you can do the following:

```
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat(yourImage.size(), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0)); // creates an empty mask of your image size
cv::rectangle(mask, yourRect, cv::Scalar(255), -1);
```

but keep in mind, that `cv::Rect` is much more efficient in both: memory consumption and computation speed.

So if you can reformulate your problem to only use rectangular ROIs (so no complement possible), I would really use it this way instead of using masks!

Comment: can you draw some images of cases that show how you interpret `maximum area rectangle containing rect1 but not rect2`?

Answer (score 7):

C++ way (cv::Rect), you can easily say

```
interesect  = r1 & r2;
```

[Refer to this link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=rect#Rect_).  All the operations are given in the documentation.

```
// In addition to the class members, the following operations 
// on rectangles are implemented:

// (shifting a rectangle by a certain offset)
// (expanding or shrinking a rectangle by a certain amount)
rect += point, rect -= point, rect += size, rect -= size (augmenting operations)
rect = rect1 & rect2 (rectangle intersection)
rect = rect1 | rect2 (minimum area rectangle containing rect2 and rect3 )
rect &= rect1, rect |= rect1 (and the corresponding augmenting operations)
rect == rect1, rect != rect1 (rectangle comparison)
```

Comment: see my answer, complement doesnt result in a rect, so how do you want to represent it? you might want to work with MASKS instead! For CV_8UC1 masks, complement is `255-mask`, union is `mask1+mask2`

Comment: Thanks, I understand it well, Can you please elaborate on how to use mask? Any link to documentation?

Comment: added some more information to my answer. would be nice to upvote Rahul galgali's answer and JTejedor's answer since they are correct for Rect objects.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I am not sure if this solves your question ( I think yes), but from [CV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html), I extract this:

In addition to the class members, the following operations on rectangles are implemented:

- rect += point, rect -= point, rect += size, rect -= size (augmenting
  operations)
- **rect = rect1 & rect2** (rectangle intersection)
- **rect =  rect1 | rect2** (minimum area rectangle containing rect2 and rect3 )
- rect &= rect1, rect |= rect1 (and the corresponding augmenting
  operations) rect == rect1, rect != rect1 (rectangle comparison)

Comment: What's the equivalent of this C++ rectangle intersection expression in Java?